# How can I avoid text flickering at the very end of a jQuery animation [ fadeIn( ) or animate( ) ]?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fadein, flicker

How can I avoid text flickering at the very end of an animation [ fadeIn( ) or animate( ) ] when using jQuery? This seems to only happen for font size < 40px.

**See the problem in the fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/HV7Az/8/

As you'll notice, *the only solution I've found is to animate the opacity to 99% instead of 100%*. This seems like a poor solution to me.

I've tried using various HTML formats, like fading out a parent div instead of the actual text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this cross-browser, but with webkit-based browsers I believe it has something to do with the GPU acceleration. I tested my theory by adding the following:

```
.animate-99, .animate-100 {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

With this in place, I **think** the font is rendered and faded, where in your jsfiddle, it is rerendered when the opacity hits 100%. This may or may not be an issue in IE9/10/Gecko browsers; you'll have to test there and see if you can trick the acceleration by antialiasing the text.